# Reference equality check (on tables) even when __eq was defined in metatable

Tags: lua, equality

Is there some construction that allows to compare references to tables even when there is __eq function defined in their metatables. In Python there is a difference between == and "is", in Java there is a difference between "equals" method and ==.

Comment: [yes](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-rawequal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Lua 3.5 Reference Manual: 6.1 Basic Functions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-rawequal)

> ```
> rawequal (v1, v2)
> ```
>
> Checks whether `v1` is equal to `v2`, without invoking the `__eq`
>   metamethod. Returns a boolean.